# LINQ ASP .net mvc actionresult CREATE

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This is my code of the ActionResult Create method:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FileStatusID, Name, MinValue, MaxValue")] fileStatusModel FILeStatusModel, TBL_FileStatus tBL_FileStatus) //include tem os valores que vamos inserir na view
{
    var userID = ((SessionModel)Session["SessionModel"]).UserID; // get current user id
    using (var query = new Core_DBEntities)
    {
        var query1 = ??????????????
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TBL_FileStatus item = new TBL_FileStatus()
        {
            Name = FILeStatusModel.Name,
            MinValue = FILeStatusModel.MinValue,
            MaxValue = FILeStatusModel.MaxValue,
            Ative = true,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            CreateBy = userID
        };

        db.TBL_FileStatus.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

And this is my SQL query:

```
DECLARE @p_valuemin INT
DECLARE @p_valuemax INT

SET @p_valuemin = 9   
SET @p_valuemax = 183

IF @p_valuemin >= @p_valuemax
    RAISERROR('@p_valuemin deve ser menor que o @p_valuemax', 16, 1)

SELECT *
FROM [TBL_FileStatus]
WHERE Ative = 1 AND ((@p_valuemin BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)
OR ((@p_valuemax BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM [TBL_FileStatus]
WHERE Ative = 1 AND ((MinValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax)
OR ((MaxValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)

those 2 values will represent the textbox of create
SET @p_valuemin = 9   
SET @p_valuemax = 183
```

My question is:

I want to join this SQL query with the ActionResult Create, to make a condition before clicking on the create button.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: you want call this query  or storeprocedure from your Create method ?

Comment: Call this query from my create method.
Or, its better the store procedure?

Answer (score 1):

If you require to call a stored procedure then Entity Framework has the `SqlQuery()` method.

You can call your stored procedure like this:

```
var p_valuemin = new SqlParameter
                     {
                         ParameterName = "p_valuemin",
                         Value = 9
                     };
var p_valuemax = new SqlParameter
                     {
                         ParameterName = "p_valuemax",
                         Value = 183
                     };

var query = "GetFileStatus @p_valuemin, @p_valuemax";

var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<GetFileStatus>(query, p_valuemin, p_valuemax).ToList();
```

Here `p_valuemin` and `p_valuemax` are your SQL Server stored procedure parameters, and as mentioned in query `GetFileStatus` is your stored procedure name and `GetFileStatus` is your result model like your query returned result entity from the stored procedure

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<GetFileStatus>(query,p_valuemin, p_valuemax).ToList();
```

for calling a stored procedure.

Your result `GetFileStatus`  model looks like

```
public class GetFileStatus
{
    public int FileStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it helps you and let me know if require any more information.

Comment: Thanks :)      it helps a lot